# SVN autoupdate from commits from any user

Tags: svn

hi i was wondering if is any chance that a working copy of a svn repository  makes autoupdate when the repository gets a new commit from any user ,
i want be able to do this because i want  my web site looks like the one in my repository or is any other way to accomplish this ?? I have control of the subversion server I have a dedicated server.

Comment: Use a distributed system so that you can keep deployment and development repository separate (just `git push deploy` or something similar to deploy, setting up your remotes. Probably something similar for hg, bzr, darcs, or what have you)

Comment: Simply create a script for svn post-commit event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577234/how-to-install-svn-post-commit-hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SVN notifier. http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/, which will notify you if the repository is updated, or you set up a batch script that runs 'svn update' very frequently.