# How to create Javadoc on the target (SVN-) server using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, svn, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I want to create the Javadoc files of my project **on** the SVN-server right **after** I commited it, meaning that **I want the server to do the work**.

I already looked in the [maven-javadoc-plugin examples](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/) section, but I could not find a suitable solution. (Maybe I just didn't understand it, I am new to Maven. If so, please be lenient and explain it to me)

It is important to notice, that I do not want Maven to generate the Javadoc on every build as it would be a big perfomance loss. I could just figure out, that `<reporting/>` should be the correct location.

I am using eclipse IDE for Java EE developers and Maven 3.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to create a [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) that invokes the [`javadoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) utility directly on the command line.

A post-commit hook is a script that is executed by the SVN server right after a successful commit. To create a post-commit hook, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7577234/1743880) (or [this blog](http://www.codersrevolution.com/blog/Creating-a-postcommit-hook-for-Subversion)). Basically, it comes down to modifying the `post-commit.tmpl` template script that is located in the `hooks` directory of your SVN server.

The script will need to execute the `javadoc` utility. It will depend on your current OS and SVN repository directory structure, but assuming Linux and a project called `myProject` with parent package `com`, it could be:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

/path/to/jdk/bin/javadoc -d ${REPOS}/myProject/target/javadoc -sourcepath "${REPOS}/myProject/src/main/java" -subpackages com
```

In this script, `REPOS` refers to the location of the SVN repository. This hook will invoke `javadoc` and tells it to store the generated Javadoc inside the `target` folder of `myProject` of all the classes inside `src/main/java` with common subpackage `com`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one question left: What is the #!/bin/sh for windows?

Comment: @DoRe Actually, there no such thing for Windows. You will need to create a batch script. SVN invokes it with 2 parameters (`$1` and `$2` above, but it is a different syntax for batch scripts).

Comment: Yeh, I found this 

_SET REPOS..._ thing. Man I hate windows. Thanks anyway :)